# How do i specify the int index of a list when adding a new item with a class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have this:

```
MyUniversalClass ourtempclass = new MyUniversalClass();
List<MyUniversalClass> mylist = new List<MyUniversalClass>();

ourtempclass.ID = i;
ourtempclass.DisplayName = con.DisplayName;
ourtempclass.PhoneNumber = con.PhoneNumbers.First().PhoneNumber;                       
mylist.Add(ourtempclass);
```

but i want to be able to do something like this: (it doesnt compile)

```
mylist[3].Add(ourtempclass);
```

so that i add (ourtempclass) to the third (4th if you include 0) item of mylist, instead of it adding it to the first, second, and third, therefore replacing everything i had previously.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method to insert at a particular location of list

```
list.Insert(int Index, Item item);
```

so instead of `mylist[3].Add(ourtempclass);`

do `mylist.Insert(3, ourtempclass);`

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit of C# - you can't expect to write your whole app via StackOverflow!

Comment: as I mentioned in answer try this `mylist.Insert(3, ourtempclass);`

Comment: @ColinE thats what im doing - learning C#. Thats why i asked in the first place!

Comment: @HarisHasan thanks it didnt show your full answer for some reason when i viewed it the first time, then after i added my comment it showed up

Comment: @davekats Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: @HarisHasan i can in 2 minutes.. kind of weird there's a time limit.

Comment: @davekats Don't listen to the idiots.  Keep learning and asking questions, that's what StackOverflow is for! :) :)